# binary summation with exact precision

Tags: java, binary

I am using following code to do binary summation:

```
class dump{
public static void main(String[] args){
    final int number0 = Integer.parseInt("000", 2);
    final int number1 = Integer.parseInt("1", 2);

    final int sum = number0 + number1;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(sum));

}
}
```

The problem is that I do not get the exact precision of the answer - eg 000 + 1 or 00 + 1 both resolve to answer as 1.
Since I intend to use the result as the key in a hashmap ,the non-uniqueness of the result is a problem.
How do I get 00+1=>01 or 000+1 =>001.

Comment: You'll need the key to be a string

Comment: Numbers are just like that. 0=00=000=00000... and 0+1=1...

Comment: To be clear, you'd want `001+1` to be `002`? Note, this stinks of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You *did* get the exact precision of the answer. The answer is `1`. "This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s."

Comment: Oh, reminds me of packed decimal arithmetic on IBM/360.  Or the DECIMAL type in PL/I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to save the maximum length among all binary numbers. Could be dynamically if you want. The following may give you an idea.

```
final int number0 = Integer.parseInt("000", 2);
final int number1 = Integer.parseInt("1", 2);
final int sum = number0 + number1;

int len = 3;

String output = String.format("%" + len + "s", Integer.toBinaryString(sum))
        .replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(output); // 001
```

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that I do not get the exact precision of the answer

Insignificant leading zeros have no effect on the precision of the answer: the answer `1` is exactly as precise as `001` or `00000000000001` - it is the same number.

> Since I intend to use the result as the key in a hashmap ,the non-uniqueness of the result is a problem.

It would be a problem if you were to use such a string as a key in a sorted map, because the keys would sometimes appear out of order. In a hash map, it is not a problem, because `Integer.toBinaryString(sum)` will drop leading zeros in all numbers, so you should never see numbers like `000` produced by your procedure. If such numbers do come from the outside, you can normalize them by parsing and converting to binary before using them as a hash key.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question is that you want "000" + "1" to become "001", and "00010" + "10" to become "00100". Even though I could question whether what you are trying to do here is *right*, *correct* or *a proper way to do it*. I will only try to solve the problem for you:

You will need to check the length of your inputs and then append enough zeroes.

```
public static String binSum(String a, String b) {
    final int number0 = Integer.parseInt(a, 2);
    final int number1 = Integer.parseInt(b, 2);
    final int sum = number0 + number1;
    String result = Integer.toBinaryString(sum);
    while (result.length() < Math.max(a.length(), b.length())) result = "0" + result;
    return result;
}

System.out.println(binSum("000", "1"));  // 001
System.out.println(binSum("0000", "1")); // 0001
System.out.println(binSum("10", "10"));  // 100
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString()` method returns the string representation of the unsigned integer value represented by the argument in binary (base 2).

```
System.out.println("Binary is " + Integer.toBinaryString(170));
```

Output is:

```
Binary is 10101010
```

Suggest to use some other technique to generate unique string from integer input.

For example, you can use encoded string as follows:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(new String(sum).getBytes());
System.out.println("Key " + new String(encodedBytes));
```